# PyInstaller isn't creating an .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 15.04, for reference.

The location of my .py script (the one I would like an .exe of) is: /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0.py

So I open up the terminal, and:

```
zix@meh:~$ cd pyinstaller-python3
zix@meh:~/pyinstaller-python3$ python3 pyinstaller.py --onefile --console btg_v0_5_0.py
934 INFO: PyInstaller version 3.0dev
936 INFO: wrote /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/btg_v0_5_0.spec
945 INFO: UPX is not available.
953 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3
953 INFO: checking Analysis
954 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
955 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
960 INFO: Looking for graph hooks ...
969 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
20757 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
20850 INFO: Analyzing btg_v0_5_0.py
21387 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
21400 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py
21417 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pydoc.py
21420 INFO: Processing hook   hook-encodings.py
21498 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
23148 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.sax.py
23164 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs - TODO
23165 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
23233 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
24999 INFO: Looking for eggs - TODO
25000 INFO: Using Python library /home/zix/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
25055 INFO: Warnings written to /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/build/btg_v0_5_0/warnbtg_v0_5_0.txt
25064 INFO: checking PYZ
25064 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
25065 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/build/btg_v0_5_0/out00-PYZ.pyz
26056 INFO: checking PKG
26057 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
26057 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
61273 INFO: Bootloader /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
61273 INFO: checking EXE
61274 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
61274 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
61276 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/dist/btg_v0_5_0
zix@meh:~/pyinstaller-python3$
```

And so I looked in /home/zix/pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/dist/, but all that's in the folder is an "executable" file named "btg_v0_5_0" (no .exe extension).
I'm not even sure what this is. Is it a Linux executable? If so, why can't I run it? I double-click it, and nothing happens. My game (BTG) is a basic text adventure that runs in the console/terminal. Running btg_v0_5_0.py works just fine.
To reiterate, my goal is to get a working .exe file (btg_v0_5_0.exe) that can be run standalone on Windows, and will simply open up in cmd.exe/Command Prompt.
Is there something I'm doing wrong, or just forgot? Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Following sideshowbarker's comment, I went into the terminal and ran the following command: `pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/dist/btg_v0_5_0`
 And I get the following:

```
zix@meh:~$ pyinstaller-python3/btg_v0_5_0/dist/btg_v0_5_0
mod is NULL - pyimod03_importersTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zix/pyinstallerpython3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 29, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_MEIPASS'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyimod03_importers'
zix@meh:~$
```

Comment: Did you try entering `./btg_v0_5_0/dist/btg_v0_5_0`  at the command line? (Rather than double-clicking on the file.)

Comment: Not an answer to this specific question, but may be useful for people landing here based on the title: On a windows machine we were having an issue with the bundle being created without errors, but the executable file missing completely. It turned out to have been quarantined by the virus scanner due to a false positive.